# Change position of words within a column

Tags: r, merge, gsub, stringr

I want to merge two datasets, but I am struggling with the following problem:

The counties in the one dataset are named in the following pattern:

```
[351] "Lindau (Bodensee), Landkreis"                  "Ostallgäu, Landkreis"                         
[353] "Unterallgäu, Landkreis"                        "Donau-Ries, Landkreis"
```

and in the other:

```
 [641] "Landkreis Nienburg/Weser"                      "Landkreis Nordhausen"                         
 [643] "Landkreis Nordsachsen"                         "Landkreis Nordwestmecklenburg"                
 [645] "Landkreis Northeim"                            "Landkreis Nürnberger Land"                    
 [647] "Landkreis Oberallgäu"                          "Landkreis Oberhavel"                          
 [649] "Landkreis Oberspreewald-Lausitz"               "Landkreis Oder-Spree"
```

Can somebody help me with some line of code to put all of the expressions in the following shape

```
"Nordsachsen, Landkreis"
```

Comment: As a starter: `help("gsub")` and `gsub("^(Landkreis) (.+)$", "\\2, \\1", "Landkreis Nordsachsen")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to put them all in the other format since you have the comma to nicely delineate. But to answer your question as asked, assuming there is only one space, this should do the trick:

```
myfunc <- function(s) {
    el <- strsplit(s, ' ')[[1]]
    return(paste0(el[2], ', ', el[1]))
}

myvec <- sapply(vector_of_strings, myfunc)
```

If you go the other way you can split on the comma in case there are names with additional spaces in them:

```
myfunc <- function(s) {
    el <- strsplit(s, ',')[[1]]
    el <- trimws(el)
    return(paste0(el[2], ' ', el[1]))
}

myvec <- sapply(vector_of_strings, myfunc)
```

EDIT: if all the entries begin with `Landkreis` you could implement something more specific to your context and less generalizable with regex:

```
s <- "Landkreis Nordhausen"
trimws(gsub('(Landkreis)(.*?$)', '\\2, \\1', s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a common, fixed-length prefix, you can use separate to remove and then paste0 to attach.

A tidyr solution to shift a common prefix to a common suffix:

```
    a <- data.frame(x = c('long words', 'long day', 'long time'))

    a %>%
      separate(x, c('A','B'), sep = 5) %>%
      mutate(
        B = paste0(B,', long')
      ) %>%
      select(-A) # to remove
```